# regex to change filenames

Tags: regex, batch-file, rename, filenames

I'm sure there is a simple solution I'm missing here.

Please see below.

I need to rename these files basically by removing the preceding zero from the last section of the filename.  It's tricking me when I hit double digits in the filename.  (filename will never go above 99 in the last section).

| original | change to |
| --- | --- |
| MM_052823_A001 | MM_052823_A01 |
| MM_052823_A002 | MM_052823_A02 |
| MM_052823_A003 | MM_052823_A03 |
| MM_052823_A004 | MM_052823_A04 |
| MM_052823_A005 | MM_052823_A05 |
| MM_052823_A006 | MM_052823_A06 |
| MM_052823_A007 | MM_052823_A07 |
| MM_052823_A008 | MM_052823_A08 |
| MM_052823_A009 | MM_052823_A09 |
| MM_052823_A010 | MM_052823_A10 |
| MM_052823_A011 | MM_052823_A11 |
| MM_052823_A012 | MM_052823_A12 |
| MM_052823_A013 | MM_052823_A13 |
| MM_052823_A014 | MM_052823_A14 |
| MM_052823_A015 | MM_052823_A15 |
| MM_052823_A016 | MM_052823_A16 |
| MM_052823_A017 | MM_052823_A17 |
| MM_052823_B001 | MM_052823_B01 |

Would greatly appreciate any leads on this!
TIA!

Comment: It's not clear to me what exactly you want: a dos rename command using regex? Or a regex you could use in an editor to generate the command? Or...something else?

Comment: If you're trying to rename files, why would you not use an existing utility like [RenameMaster](http://www.joejoesoft.com/vcms/108/)?

Comment: I need to be able to script and schedule this to run on a daily basis.  Most programs I've come across are run manually and done for one time events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can isolate the last zero
like this  `0(\d+$)`
then replace with the capture group  `$1`
Use the *Multiline* Flag if doing several lines at a time.

https://regex101.com/r/dXAk4D/1

Answer (score 0):

Below regex will give you two grouped outcomes.
First is the 3 digit format with leading zero and the second is in the format you expects, without leading zero.

`^\S+_\d+_\S(0(\d\d))$`

**Example:**
File name: MM_052823_A007
Group 1: 007
Group 2: 07

You may replace the first group with the second using any applicable script or code piece.

Regex: https://regex101.com/r/OyJcrZ/1

Comment: How is the actual substitution done? You can replace *the entire match* with some value but how do you replace a portion of the entire match (e.g. capture group 1 in your case) with some value (e.g. capture group 2 in your case)? You could use, although I am not saying this as the best solution, `(\S+_\d+_\S)(0(\d\d))$` and replace with `$1$3`. See [this](https://regex101.com/r/homCo2/1). **You need to capture every part of the complete match that you wish to keep** unless your regex engine provides you the offset and length of capture groups and you are willing to do the replacement yourself.